# Combine two Firebase List Observables in Angularfire 2

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

i have two Firebase List Observables. These Lists are both the same but only from two different users. Is it possible to combine these two lists, so that i have one big list?

For example someting like this:

```
this.totalCards = cardsOfUserOne + cardsOfUserTwo;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please add some more code to the post? How do you get those lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can combine the lists as below
**example** :

```
this.list1= this.fireDb.list('/cardsOfUserOne ');
this.list2= this.fireDb.list('/cardsOfUserTwo ');

this.list1.subscribe((cardsOfUserOne ) => {

   this.list2.subscribe((cardsOfUserTwo ) => {

   this.totalCards = cardsOfUserOne.concat(cardsOfUserTwo);

   })

})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works very good in my model. Do you know if there is a way to use the concat function in the template in combination with the async pipe? Something like this:   <li *ngFor="concat(cardsOfUserOne,cardsOfUserTwo)  | async" >